# Do I need an LED driver for my application?

Tags: voltage, led, led-driver, ohms-law

My LED has a forward voltage of 17.2V and a current of 700mA at 85 degrees C. I'm using a heat sink on the LED so thermal effects can be ignored.

To power my circuit, I'm using an AC/DC wall mount which outputs a voltage of 18V connected to a power barrel jack on my PCB.

To achieve a 700 mA current, I would need a resistor ~ 1 Ohm. Calculation: V = IR, R = (18-17.2)/.7 = 1.14 Ohm.

At 700mA current, this resistor would dissipate power of (I^2)(R) = 0.49W.

I"m struggling to see why I would need an LED driver in this situation?

Given the close match between input voltage and the forward voltage of the LED, the resistor would only be dissipating little power and therefore little heat.

Is the risk the power wall mount temporarily outputs a higher voltage, say 20V? As insurance against this scenario, I could split up the resistance into multiple resistors in series to distribute the heat dissipation?

Comment: *I'm using a heat sink on the LED so thermal effects can be ignored.* If you need to use a heat sink, I **bet** the opposite is true!

Comment: A resistor dissipating half a Watt is also a relatively large, bulky transistor, and it's going to need so way to get these 0.5 W of heat away. Do you plan on mounting it on the same heat sink?

Comment: and: having multiple resistors: how is that much easier or cheaper than a simple constant current driver? (You're just delivering arguments for a driver, not against one, so I'm confused)

Comment: The risk is more that the forward voltage deviates from what you expect, upsetting the resistor calculation by a large margin resulting in a large change in current.

Comment: If you look at actual resistor/LED pairs in products, usually the resistor is chosen to dissipate at least 20% of the total power in the system.  The reason for this is that the forward voltage is not remotely constant, so you need a relatively large resistor to compensate.  In this case you are dissipating 4% of the energy in the resistor, so this will not a very stable system.  Consider increasing your power supply to 24v and then reevaluating what you should use.

Comment: The Vf of you individual LED and the exact output voltage of your power supply under load will vary. Take the extremes of both values from the respective datasheet and calculate the resulting current. The results will surprise you!

Comment: How did you verify Vf and Vcc vs If?

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 The forward voltage and current came from the LED datasheet.

Comment: I also asked for the Vcc supply curve .. you can use a series R with no problem, just supply tolerance variations.  Does the Meanwell  regulator work?  Since the LED incremental resistance for 12W will be < = 1/Pmax = 0.1 Ohms , adding Rs of 1 Ohm or so will be stable and regulate the current.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. With such a low overhead voltage vs. the cumulative variability in forward voltage over the whole string, it will be nearly impossible to get the load resistor ‘just right’. You’ll struggle with either the LEDs being too dim, or they will have very short life due to overstress, even with the heatsink.

Off the shelf constant current LED drivers are plentiful and cheap. Use one of those instead.

Comment: Thank you. Can you recommend a constant current LED driver for this application?

Comment: Use one that is rated for at least 24V max that has the current you need. Example: https://www.ledsupply.com/led-drivers/phihong-pda030b-700c

Comment: I was looking for one much cheaper.

Comment: @Jai Sorry, recommendations for specific products are off-topic here.

Comment: @Jai Thats why product suggestions are off-topic. You said you needed suggestions without any specs, then you got a suggestion, and only afterwards you mentioned you have some specs or limitations like price which you never mentioned you have.

Comment: I posted that as an example. Phihong is a reputable supplier, as is Mean Well. If you want cheap try Alibaba or similar, but note that safety and reliability may be of issue with parts sourced from there.

Comment: OK sorry and thanks for the help.

Comment: Would I need a heat sink for the LED driver?

Comment: @Jai We can't possibly know if your LED driver needs a heat sink. That would depend on which LED driver you use. An efficient driver would not heat much by itself. An inefficient will. It also depends if you bolt the 85C degree LEDs right onto the driver, or will the driver be separate and far away from the hot LEDs.

Comment: @Justme https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/mean-well-usa-inc/LDD-700LS/7704762 - That's the LED driver I'm using. It will be on the PCB while my LEDs will be separate off the board, connected by wires.

Comment: @jai Why not try reading the datasheet yourself? The driver is about 95% efficient, so if the LED takes 12W, so less than 1W is dissipated as heat in the driver. Besides, how would you even attach a heat sink to such a modue? However, it is specified to operate at full current only to 71 degrees C, so 700mA operation at 85 C is not possible. It also reads "cooling by free air convection" in the features of the module.

Answer (score 2):

That is exactly why you need a LED driver.

The LED voltage will definitely not be exactly 17.2V. It will vary due to manufacturing tolerances, temperature and age. The DC power supply will also not be exactly 18.0V for same reasons, typically power supplies are rated for 5% initial tolerance. The resistor will most likely not be exactly 1.14 ohms either as such a standard value does not exist, so let's assume it has a 5% tolerance or just maybe 2% tolerance.

Sure, when everything is their perfect nominal values, you get the perfect nominal 700mA.

But what happens if the resistor is 2% too small? Well, the current only goes up about 2% to 716 mA. The LED might survive that.

So what happens if the LED voltage is 100mV less, or 17.1V instead? The current goes up by 12% to 789 mA.

What happens if the power supply voltage is 1% too high? The current goes up by 22% to 860 mA.

So even the slightest differences to nominal values cause extremely large deviations in the current.

Answer (score 1):

If you have just  1V to spare you can dissipate low power and regulate the current with 2 transistors, one being a TO-220.  Otherwise use a TO-220 FET if << 1V margin.  and use PWM if > 2V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fitimn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Adjust Re for 600 to 700 mV drop

[For similar Sim or  fancier same design with a 10k pot dimmer.](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDOB0YzCsICMZIDYDMAWATKg7HOgJwAciqclIm6I2IcEcApgLSKIBQA7iOnPWxxUfAXRIk%20PUYOyYZdMJK6I89fvUSZ5GpInoQ8SIpESTsEM%20CgIArgDsATswDmtgDYBDAC7MAJiAAzrYADiHuAJ4gnC4K6OgiuroQYNJylqgQ6caanI50mJZEgoUFKUiwMHlxCQrYEtYoqJzedGri5qX1kpYg7GhkJGCYiHAkAmDoHD2QAmN4pCSo2IhYcEQMEH7MAGaeHt7S6MNlbSVZaV1XWe2pvEm12fEiqVggO9x%20jgD2IQA6AEdVJBNCATOhsGwOFBhoITHJ0AQ8DgISsSLcoHhOOR1GJyBBdBZzO9Pj9-kC8CCkNTEJi4NVdPiFFp5JZODs%20CcnmInppZptLhkCXjMnQ0u1spLSnc6g1nh1wNVsBKGsrztYzLBBZz5E9ajLjrrVSqetjkXxHnKuQ1achYFAiERGJUXTBbWAANYgELfQ73S2SCE3AxHCw6vhhtWKwq0boR6jkMEvPQAfVQmBTeBTNEoKYsKZQiALKaL%20f0AHU-oEADIAUQAIpwAB4MEYWjbCWlYejySQAIwiVYAKpAAMqQZutkRaSSZBCjWnyfQVD1V%20sASwAtpvmI5OEA)